# In FCE container translation - show items of original element

Tags: typo3

I have yet another question regarding translations of FCE elements in TYPO3.

The Problem:
I have a FCE Container that can hold several items. The container and the items have translations.

When I add or remove another item to the original container, I have to add/remove this item to all the translations as well. This is pretty annoying, because I want to show the same items in all translations.

Now what I want to do is change the output of my FCE so that always the items of the original container are shown.

This is the TS of a standard content field in T3, maybe someone can rewrite this:

```
10 = RECORDS
10.source.current = 1
10.table = tt_content
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the language of the FCE to "All" (Edit -> Language -> All)? If you add a new content element to the FCE, it will be visible in all languages.

Comment: That's sounds quite useful, but how do I get the "all" option in language? Do I have to set something first? I can only choose between the three languages I set up in this system.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your FCE

[image]

Then Select [All] in language:

[image]

Comment: I really would love to do that, but as I said "all" is not available, only the languages I set up in T3. I'm pretty sure I have to set something first, but so far I couldn't find a hint what this is.